# What does the following javascript do?

Tags: javascript, php, html, cookies

I'm having trouble understanding what the following javascript does. took it in a lab session and even tested it(or at least tried to since it did not work with me like the other students, it kept asking me to login and never showed the welcome message). the lab is about XSS attacks and the instructor told us that this script could be exploited, and I don't see how?.

don't mind the comments; I added them to help me understand when tracing the code

```
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Mobile code:: XSS cookie example </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="SecureM.css"/>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script language="Javascript">
    function checkCookie(){
      //Here is the initialization of variables to be used for this function
      var lf = "\n";        //character for next line (lf = line feed)
      var CookieString = document.cookie; //cookies are accessible through the document.cookie property
      var CookieSet = CookieString.split(';');  //This splits document.cookie on semicolons. CookieSet becomes an array containing all cookies that are set for this domain and path.
      var SetSize = CookieSet.length;
      var CookiePieces;
      var ReturnValue="";       //set default empty return if no cookie found
      var x = 0;
      for (x = 0; ((x < SetSize) && (ReturnValue == "")); x++){
        CookiePieces = CookieSet[x].split('=');
        if (CookiePieces[0].substring(0,1) == ' ' ){
          CookiePieces[0] =
            CookiePieces[0].substring(1, CookiePieces[0].length);
        }       //end if statement
        if (CookiePieces[0] == "superSecretPassword"){
          ReturnValue = CookiePieces[1];
        }       //end if statement
      }         //end for loop
      return ReturnValue;   
    }   //end checkCookie() function

    if (checkCookie() == ""){ // no cookie found, relocate to login.php
      window.location.href="login.php";
    }
  </script>

  <?
    if (isset($_GET["username"])){
      $cur_username = $_GET["username"];
    }
    else if (isset($_POST["username"])){
      $cur_username = $_POST["username"];
    }
    else if (isset($_COOKIE["username"])){
     $cur_username = $_COOKIE["username"];
    }
    else{
      $cur_username = "No Name";
    }
    echo "<strong>LOGIN SUCCESSFULL!</strong><br/><br/>";
    echo "<strong>Thank you, ".$cur_username." your information have been updated</strong>";
    //


  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

anyhow, help in explaining this is greatly appreciated. lastly, I hope my english wasn't that bad..

edit: um, wow.. why is this getting voted down..? is it so bad to ask for help/explanation??

Comment: It seems to be mainly vulnerable as the supersecret password is stored directly in a cookie that is available on the clientside, so any user can access it or steal it.

Comment: Displaying `$cur_username` in the PHP portion, unescaped is vulnerable to XSS. If a malicious link was shared as `yourscript?username=<badjavascriptcode>` that `<badjavascriptcode>` would be executed.  You would need to use `htmlspecialchars($cur_username)` to mitigate it.

Comment: I guess the comments describe the whole code. What do you really want to understand.

Comment: Since this seems to be from a lab assignment (computer science major?) The absolute BEST thing you can do is go to your professor and tell them you don't get it. You might not be the only student who didn't get it, and it will allow the professor to potentially explain things in a different way. I did that when I was in college to get our professor to re-explain something (interfaces in OOP to be exact). Because of that, I understand interfaces to a level I never thought possible :)

Comment: thank you very much for replying, but I still don't completely understand, like what are the lines in the for loop doing? how is this check function working? etc. I honestly have no prior knowledge with javascripts until I took this course

Comment: @Zarazthuztra: yes, it is from a lab assignment; course is secure mobile code. I agree with you, but the thing is right now it's winter break and I tried sending the instructor an email and I have yet to get a reply(I sent it 4 days ago..sigh), right after winter break I have a lab test and i'm expected to understand the entire material including this.

Comment: You've got plenty of time to do some studying! Additionally, does your professor have a phone number? I'm serious, he's the BEST source of help with this sort of thing, way better than SO, because he's going to know your learning style best.

Comment: @Zarazthuztra again, thank you! I think he does? idk. but I  will look for it, and hopefully i'll find it.

Comment: I hope you do too, understanding this sort of thing is critical to your grade :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScript is irrelevant. The exploit is through the PHP.

User input (`$_GET["username"]` and `$_POST["username"]`):

- Come from the browser
- Can be given to the browser by another site (or an email) via a link or a form
- Can contain JavaScript
- Are output directly onto the page with no sanitization

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to post an answer with a little more information, even though Quentin has done a fantastic job pointing out the answer.

Some of this required that you understand exactly what the $_GET, $_POST, and $_COOKIE super globals do. Here are some examples as to how you might exploit these, and what each means.

$_GET: This superglobal array is set whenever someone makes an HTTP GET request to your page, and the PHP is then executed server side. When the PHP code checks it, it has access to the parameters passed to it, via the URL, which is typically how a GET request is created. Given the PHP code used here, all a malicious user would have to do is enter the URL (in THEIR code)

http://yourvulnerablesite.com/?username=root');
        exit();

$_POST: This superglobal array is set whenever someone makes an HTTP POST request to your page, and the PHP is then excuted server side. This is probably not going to be as likely as a GET request because it takes a tiny bit more effort to implement. It's also not going to be as effective because the JavaScript that sets the logged in cookie probably won't run. The easiest way to do this? A browser extension that allows arbitrary HTTP requests to be made with the specified parameters with the specified method, such as [this one.](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/httprequester/)

$_COOKIE: This superglobal array is set whenever someone visits your site, no matter what, and it's set to all the cookies detected in the user's request to your site that were site by the same domain. All a user has to do is visit your vulnerable site one time, or create a cookie with the appropriate domain, and enter in a username, such as root. When they then enter your site again, they'll be logged in as that user without so much as just going to http://myvulnerablesite.com

There are some additional problems here besides these vulnerabilities with regards to always trusting that the user is actually using your site (as the exercise is about XSS, not overall problems with a site) but the password is actually never being checked, and the JavaScript is quite literally irrelevant as Quentin pointed out. It does absolutely nothing towards logging a user in since the password is not checked with the PHP.

I hope this gives you some insight into exactly what's going on here. You seem to understand the JavaScript ok, so I won't go over that :)